# VC.isHidden = true not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a Viewcontroller `ThirdViewControllerPassenger` which has multiple subviews on it, including a `UICollectionView` called `collectionView`with horizontally scrolling Cards. So far, so good. I have written code to be executed from a tap action from inside the uicollectionviewcells. Tapping the action does work and prints to console. However, by pressing one of these cards I want to hide the whole `UICollectionView`. I have set up an onTap Function as shown here:

```
@objc func onTap(_ gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (gesture.state == .ended) {
        /* action */
        if favCoordinate.latitude == 1.0 && favCoordinate.longitude == 1.0 {
            //There has been an error OR the User has pressed the new Address button
            
            //do
        }else{
            ThirdViewControllerPassenger().collectionView.isHidden = true
            if ThirdViewControllerPassenger().collectionView.isHidden == true {
                print("done!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have already been troubleshooting a bit. I have tested `ThirdViewControllerPassenger().collectionView.isHidden = true` from `ThirdViewControllerPassenger` directly, which worked. It does not work, however, from a cell. The "done!" print never gets printed to console, so the call never arrives. I wonder why or what I am doing wrong.
Don't mind the first if statement, that function is not written yet. That should not matter. I am guessing that the rest of my code would not lead to any more clues.

Answer (score 3):

Every `ThirdViewControllerPassenger()` here

```
ThirdViewControllerPassenger().collectionView.isHidden = true
if ThirdViewControllerPassenger().collectionView.isHidden == true {
  print("done!")
}
```

is a new instance not the real one , you need to get access to the real shown istance

```
delegate.collectionView.isHidden = true
if delegate.collectionView.isHidden == true {
   print("done!")
}
```

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb but delegate is not found in my scope... What exactly is called with delegate?

Comment: `delegate ` is a vaiable that you should declare in current vc to reference `ThirdViewControllerPassenger` ,  tell how you show the vc that contains the above method ? and according to that when you present it assign the delegate to the `ThirdViewControllerPassenger` instance

Comment: It is a bit complicated since it is a `UICollectionView`, but here we go:

Comment: Basically: I create a collectionView in my ThirdViewControllerPassenger, which then calls a function that will create cells for it (`CellBuilder`).  Those cells get passed back and get added to CellForIndexAt. Inside this Cell File is the method I have shown above.